# How can i change my timestamp date in PGadmin?

Tags: sql, timestamp

i changed my datefield to timestamp in PGadmin but now all the fields have '2020-04-24 00:00:00'.
But i want that the time of all the fields have the following value '2020-04-24 12:00:00' so instead that all my field values have 00:00:00 they have 12:00:00. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works...

```
    update table
    set date = date + interval '12 hour';
```